# Vim 80 character marker without adding spaces

Tags: vim

I have a marker at 80 characters which I set using

```
:set colorcolumn=80
```

But when I do this, if I'm highlighting and copying text to the clipboard, I get spaces after the last character on the line.  This is very annoying if I'm sending code snippets to people which requires copying using the clipboard.

Is there a way to get the marker at 80 characters without those added spaces?

Also, I have tried highlighting characters after col 80 (and less), but I prefer to see the marker instead of guessing where 80 characters will be.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because your terminal is handling selections, and has no idea that the spaces vim is using to print the color column are not "real" characters. (ie: the terminal only knows what's in its display, not what's in vim's buffer). If you use gvim it doesn't have this issue.

In the console you can simulate the gvim behavior somewhat by using the `mouse` and `clipboard` settings. Something like this should work:

```
set mouse=a clipboard=autoselect
```

This will cause vim to take over mouse handling even in a terminal, and will tell it to automatically place selected text in the `"*` register, which corresponds to X11's primary selection. You can set `clipboard` to `autoselectplus` if you prefer the clipboard over the primary selection.

Another option is to just use vim commands instead of the mouse to do this sort of copy and paste. You can manually copy to X's primary selection or clipboard by specifying `"*` or `"+` as the register, respectively. eg: `"*y<text-object>` or in visual mode just `"*y` will yank to the selection, and then you can middle-click (or shift-insert in some software) to "paste".

A variation of this is to make everything you yank into the default register in vim also end up in the X selection or clipboard:

```
set clipboard=unnamed       " copies to X's primary selection
```

or

```
set clipboard=unnamedplus   " copies to X's clipboard
```

Note that *all* of these require a build of vim that has X support compiled in and `$DISPLAY` must be set accordingly.

See also:

- `:help 'clipboard'`
- `:help 'mouse'`
- `:help X11`